# What does the notation $x\ast y$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, notation

$(\Bbb N, ∗)$, where $x\ast  y=x^y$ and $\Bbb N$ is the set of natural numbers.

It isn't multiplication. Is it undefined?

This isn't something I've ever come across, and I can't find any information on it.

I don't think it's modulo, either.

Comment: It is a definition.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

It means the relation $x\ast y$ is *defined to be* "$x$ to the power of $y$" for $x,y\in\Bbb N$. For example, if $x=2$ and $y=3$, then $x\ast y=2^3=2\times 2\times 2=8$.

Comment: That isn't what's confusing me, it's the asterisk.

Comment: I've edited my answer, @KAYoung.

Comment: Thank you!.....

Comment: You're welcome, @KAYoung.

Answer (score 3):

It is a definition. They're defining an operation $\ast$ on $\Bbb N$, different from addition $+$ and multiplication $\cdot$, by the formula $x \ast y \doteq x^y$. For example, $2 \ast 3 = 8$, also $5 \ast 3 = 125$, then $3 \ast 5 = 243$, etc.